# oclint: error: violations exceed threshold via Jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, oclint

can't win oclint. I really don't know what to do, i try to make some changes in build script but nothing help.

script:

```
$XCODE_COMMAND -reporter json-compilation-database:${WORKSPACE}/compile_commands.json clean build
#${oclint.path}/bin/oclint-xcodebuild
${oclint_path}/bin/oclint-json-compilation-database \
${oclint_in} ${oclint_ex} -- -o=$BUILD_WORK_DIR/oclint/lint.xml \
-report-type=pmd -stats -max-priority-1=9999 -max-priority-2=9999 -max-priority-3=9999 -rc LONG_LINE=500 -rc LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=100
sed -i .bak 's/\&\&/\&/g' "$BUILD_WORK_DIR"/oclint/lint.xml
```

mistake:

```
18:22:18 + oclint/bin/oclint-json-compilation-database -- -o=/Users/ep/jenkins- slave/workspace/test_RGP-ODC_RacingPost_iPad_staging/./build/oclint/lint.xml -report-type=pmd -stats -max-priority-   1=9999 -max-priority-2=9999 -max-priority-3=9999 -rc LONG_LINE=500 -rc LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=100
18:27:22 
18:27:22 oclint: error: violations exceed threshold
18:27:22 P1=2[9999] P2=3662[9999] P3=11784[9999] 
18:27:23 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just increase the threshold over 9999?

> maxPriority=15000
>
> ${oclint_in} ${oclint_ex} -- -o=$BUILD_WORK_DIR/oclint/lint.xml
>   -report-type=pmd -stats -max-priority-1=$maxPriority -max-priority-2=$maxPriority -max-priority-3=$maxPriority -rc LONG_LINE=500 -rc LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=100